# MySQL Stored function to return name on id input

Tags: mysql

I have this table

[image: Table data screenshot]

I want to create stored function that takes empno and returns its manager (boss) name. (one employee is boss of other employee)
this is the code i tried but it returned error 
MYSQL said: The query was empty

```
CREATE FUNCTION MANAGER1(ENO int) RETURNS varchar DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE MANAGER_NAME varchar(MAX);
    Select name into MANAGER_NAME where boss = ENO;
    RETURN varchar MANAGER_NAME

DELIMITER $$ ;
```

Comment: Dare we ask why you want to do this?

Comment: Every begin has to have an end and  RETURN varchar the varchar is not required and the return needs a terminator;

Comment: Besides the problem you are having with the syntax of the query, it won't function for the stated purpose. The function as written looks like it will return the names of subordinates of the given ID, not the manager of the given ID.

Comment: Even with END, its not working

Comment: I was solving database tasks but stuck here, the problem was. "Create a stored function MANAGER1 with parameters. It must take empno as an input and must return its manager name."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check once again with following query for creating stored function:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION getManager1(eno int(11))
RETURNS varchar(255)
DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
    DECLARE manager_name varchar(250);
    Select name into manager_name FROM employees where id = eno;
    return manager_name;
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

In your stored procedure statement, **END** tag is missing and table name is also missing in ***SELECT*** statement. I have executed query mentioned here. Please match with your query and check what is missing in your query posted in question.

Comment: Glad I could help.